# jQuery: JSON callback function never reached

Tags: ajax, json, jquery

I'm requesting a page via JSON but never reach the callback-function. Does someone know why this is happening?

```
jQuery.getJSON("'. $dnd_fileupload_dir .'dnd-medialink.php?format=json&jsoncallback=?", function(data){  
    alert("lalala");
});
```

Comment: are you making cross browser request?? if yes then use $.ajax, with dataType=jsonp

Comment: You might want to remove jsoncallback in the URL GET parameters.

Comment: @Praveen, `getJSON()` will automatically deduce from the `jsoncallback` argument that it should consider the request JSONP, so this should work as far as the jquery API is concerned. I agree, though, that using $.ajax() directly is easier to understand. @Hedge - JSONP error handling is a bit rough by nature. Do you see any javascript errors (for example, in the Firebug console)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use firebug to see what's going on. Either the request URI is incorrect and there is a 400 error, or the response is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest downloading fiddler tool and using it to watch what is sent over http. A simple search on google will get you to the fiddler website